# Oracle connection strings in blazor app with ef code

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, blazor, connection-string

I have a Blazor server project with Oracle Database. When I try to use the connection

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
"GTravelDbConnection": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));User Id=GTRAVEL;  Password=cteam;"
```

in appsettings.json  and  use in program.cs the following code

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("GTravelDbConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GTravelDbContext>(
    options => options.UseOracle(connectionString)
);
```

I get the error

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

The same connection string if used from dbcontext class

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseOracle("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));User Id=GTRAVEL;  Password=cteam;");  
    }
}
```

works with no problem.

I would be obliged if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to use a scoped service without creating a scope.  When I used the following code in program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("GTravelDbConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GTravelDbContext>(
     options => options.UseOracle(connectionString)
     
     );
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
    var customerService = services.GetRequiredService<ICustomerService>();
}
```

it all worked perfectly.

Thank you